Power BI Days in a given week of a month
I have the following columns - Week of Month, Month, Year, Date, & Days in Week.
I am trying to show in the column "Days in Week" in this format: 1 - 4, 5 - 11, etc.
In other words, I want the range of the days in that week to go into the column "Days in Week". Refer to the picture below where I show the results that I am looking for (don't pay any attention to the different colors):

The code that I am using only results in 1 - 31 which are the range of days in that month which looks like this:
Days in Week = IF('Date'[Year] = 'Date'[Year] && 'Date'[Month] = 'Date'[Month] && 'Date'[Adjusted Week Of Month] = 'Date'[Adjusted Week Of Month], MIN('Date'[Day]) & " - " & MAX('Date'[Day]), "")
The logic that I am going for is if the week, month, & year match then show the "min day in that week" "-" "max day in that week" as shown in the picture above.
Any and all help is appreciated!

If you want to calculate the result according to the method you described you can use the following dax-formula:
Days in Week = CALCULATE( DAY(MIN('Table'[Date])), ALLEXCEPT('Table', 'Table'[Year], 'Table'[Month], 'Table'[Week of Month]) ) & " - " & CALCULATE( DAY(MAX('Table'[Date])), ALLEXCEPT('Table', 'Table'[Year], 'Table'[Month], 'Table'[Week of Month]) )

This will result in the following table:


An alternative solution using just the Date column:
Days in Week = 
  var startWk = [Date] - WEEKDAY([Date], 1) + 1
  var endWk = startWk + 6
  var startMnth = EOMONTH([Date], -1) + 1
  var endMnth = EOMONTH([Date], 0)
  var startD = MAX(startWk, startMnth)
  var endD = MIN(endWk, endMnth)
  return DAY(startD) & " - " & DAY(endD)

